# Node: Sending Protobuf message to Kafka Error

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to use the HDFS kafka connector to send protobuf messages from kafka to the HDFS. My connector config looks like the following

```
{
    "name": "hdfs3-connector-test",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs3.Hdfs3SinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "test-topic",
        "hdfs.url": "hdfs://10.8.0.1:9000",
        "flush.size": "3",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://10.8.0.1:8081",
        "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "10.8.0.1:9092",
        "confluent.topic.replication.factor": "1"
    }
}
```

In order to test this, I am trying to send protobuf serialized messages in a small node application. Here are my files:

```
// data.proto

syntax = "proto3";
package awesomepackage;

message SearchRequest {
  string query = 1;
  int32 page = 2;
}
```

and my node app

```
const { Kafka } = require('kafkajs')
const protobuf = require('protobufjs')

const kafka = new Kafka({
    clientId: 'my-app',
    brokers: ['10.8.0.1:9092']
})

const producer = kafka.producer()


const run = async () => {
    await producer.connect()

    protobuf.load('data.proto', async (err, root) => {
        console.log("TESTING")
        console.log(err)
    
        let SearchRequest = root.lookupType('awesomepackage.SearchRequest')
        let payload = {query: "test", page: 2} 
    
        var errMsg = SearchRequest.verify(payload);
        console.log(errMsg)
    
        let msg = SearchRequest.create(payload)
        var buffer = SearchRequest.encode(msg).finish();
        console.log(buffer)
        await producer.send({
            topic: 'test-topic',
            messages: [
                {key: 'key1', value: buffer}
            ]
        })
    })
    
}

run()
```

However, when I run this I get the following errors:

```
Failed to deserialize data for topic test-topic to Protobuf

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Protobuf message for id -1

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
```

How do I fix this? My guess is that my protobuf schema is not registered in the kafka schema registry, but I am unsure. If this is the case, is there a way to send the schema to the registry from node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter` requires the Schema Registry, not plain serialized Protobuf. In other words, you're missing the Schema Registry part (or a manual byte creation of a "wrapped" Proto message) in the Node code

Refer [Wire Format - Confluent](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format)

---

If you would like to not use the Schema Registry, you can use the [BlueApron Protobuf Converter](https://github.com/blueapron/kafka-connect-protobuf-converter), but seems like you are using one, so best to go with the Confluent converter

Comment: So does this mean I need to first register a schema using the Schema Registry API, and then get the ID of that schema and prepend it to my protobuf message along with the magic byte?

Comment: That's one option unless there's a Node Kafka library that includes a Proto serializer like the Avro one

Comment: Read the comment in the docs about the "message indexes", however

Comment: Ah, there seems to be a potential library that can handle this: https://kafkajs.github.io/confluent-schema-registry/docs/usage.

Comment: There's a few libraries around, yeah. Wasn't sure which one had implemented non-Avro functionality yet

Comment: Just wanted to follow up, that using the StringConverter does not require the schema registry. So in this case I can send my serialized protobuf data directly to kafka and have it written to the HDFS for consumption later.

Comment: You should use ByteConverter instead if that's what you really want, but then the data will be stored in binary, rather than be in any structured format in Hadoop that can easily be queried (like Avro or Parquet)